# Any idea to execute firebase except query?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am displaying list of userid in collection and i want to exclude own user id and display rest of them in recyclerview.I searched for firebase except query and i found was startafter which there is no description for it,Can anyone have any idea about this or how this startafter can be applied?

Answer (score 1):

**Query limitations**

Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:

Queries with `a !=` clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause `where("age", "!=", "30")` is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause `where("age", "<", "30")` and one with the clause `where("age", ">", 30).`
[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)